# Input / output behaviour of dynamic latch

Tags: latch

I'm studying this dynamic latch and I wonder why, when the switch closes the second time, `in` doesn't go up to high as well.

When I consider only the switch and out, then everything makes sense. At least, when I ignore the inverse function of the latch..

However, in short: How do `in` and `out` behave, respectively, why, when the switch is closed the second time?

[image: img]

Comment: `IN` is wholly defined by its waveform shape irrespective of what the switch does.

Comment: Understand, makes sense. Does this mean out goes up again because the capacitor is discharged?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the "in" signal is being driven by a source that is strong enough to overcome any remaining charge on the input of "1".

The diagram you are showing is only a partial depiction of the system and there is no indication of what is to the left of "in".  But in an actual circuit that would be the output stage of a logic device or circuit that is designed to overcome the input capacitance of the "1" block.